# Standalone flash player navigateToURL using POST fails

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, embedded-flashplayer

Since Flash plugin has reached EOL, the only way to still use my RIA is to use the standalone version of Flash player.

I've noticed an issue with the following piece of code while testing the migration:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("/utils/function");
request.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

var data:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
data.x = encodeURIComponent(1);
data.y = encodeURIComponent(2);
data.z = encodeURIComponent('some value');
request.data = data;

navigateToURL(request, "_blank");
```

The standalone version of flash (v30.0.0.134) makes a GET request instead of the instructed POST method. The browser plugin (v32.0.0.238) opens the page correctly in a new tab as a POST request.

Why does the standalone flash convert my request in to a GET? Anybody out there who can shed some light on this issue?

Comment: StandAlone Flash Player has even more restrictions than AIR runtime, so it is safe to assume this applies to your case as well. Here: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL() *For content running in Adobe AIR, when using the navigateToURL() function, the runtime treats a URLRequest that uses the POST method (one that has its method property set to URLRequestMethod.POST) as using the GET method.*

Comment: The reason behind it is (a pure guess of mine) the following. This operation (for both SAFP or AIR application) counts as system operation '*open another application with parameters*'. GET request is just a single URL string and can be used as the parameter, while POST request is a complicated multi-line text and by no means fits a single-line string.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it qualifies as a answer, but we use this to make a POST request:

```
        handleService.url='.../something.ashx';
        handleService.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        
        var prm:Object=new Object();
        prm.par1 = "asd";
        prm.content=encodedData;
        prm.fileName=FileName;
        handleService.send(prm);
```

Instead of going for a standalone version of flash, you can package the app as a Adobe AIR runtime. We still use some apps written in Flex and have no issues with them.

If running on windows, you can package it as a native runtime and works nice.